# AWS IoT Core topic filter wildcards

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/pub-sub-policy.html) wildcard characters we use for topics throughout the mqtt protocol like `+` or `#` are treated as literals in policies. The docs recomend using `*` as a wildcard character instead but do not describe its effects.

For example will the topic filter `:topicfilter:/foo/bar/*` match topic `foo/bar/baz/gaz` or only `foo/bar/baz`?

Specifically I am trying to allow access to any topic which begins with the thing name of the policy holder. So I would like to allow access to any topic beginning with `${thingName}/` and having any number of forward slashes and url parameters following a matching `thingName`. Would `topicfilter:${thingName}/*` work or would that only work for topics with one url parameter after `thingName`?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the wildcard `*` is a catch all i.e. it will match unlimited trailing url parameters. An important thing to keep in mind is that `topicfilter` and `topic` are different and are different resources for different MQTT actions as outlined [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/action-resources.html).

Comment: The link seems to be outdated?

Comment: are you sure `:topicfilter:/foo/bar/*` works? It doesn't work for me (i.e. wild card at the end). Only `:topicfilter:/foo/bar/`works

Comment: Thanks for linking the difference between `topic` and `topicfilter` here, I was searching for it